# How does Dart fit into a conventional WebApp directory layout structure

Tags: web-applications, dart

Following the recommended directory layout for Dart 
http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/package-layout.html
I can't see how this fits into a conventional WebApp-Project...

As you can see I messed around a bit but noting feels really right. Any hints?

[image: Dir structure]

[**Update**]
Could this be a solution? It works here at least for testing purpose...
[image: Dir structure]

Comment: Perhaps you'll have to stop considering it a conventional web app project.

Comment: I think that's not the solution. There must be a way to integrate frontend and backend into one project - but maybe I found a way. Any comments on the second SS?

Comment: If you're using Maven, then the sources would be in "src/main/dart".

Comment: don't you put your server side code in the projectRoot/bin and frontend content in projectRoot/web ? seems pretty straight forward

Comment: You should define what is a "conventional WebApp". What is "conventional"? Who defined this convention? Who follows it?

Comment: I would say the Maven-structure is something like a convention. Sure - everyone is free to define his own structure but it makes sense to follow such standards. Most tools support a Maven-structure out of the box - so why not Dart?

Comment: Because Maven is for JVM based projects and Dart is not related to that. I solved this for now by having the dart stuff in a dedicated "project" and combining both at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to peacefully combine a spring(-boot) mvc project and dart as well and wasn't successful. It never felt right or had problems where dart was not build or something like that.

The maven dart plugin didn't seem to be ready for prime time, so I extracted the dart stuff into it's own project that is installed separately and I communicate to the java backend solely via rest calls.

Comment: Thats exactly the solution I came up with too.